# Visual Studio 2003 Merge Modules

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, visual-studio-2003, merge-module

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to make an install.  The application has a dependency on a DLL that was built with MFC 7.1 (from Visual Studio 2003).

Are there merge modules for MFC 7.1 or other redistributables like there are for MFC 8?  Where could they be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These merge modules are usually located in `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Merge Modules.`

Look for these files:

- `vc_user_crt71_rtl_x86_---.msm` (has msvcr71.dll)
- `vc_user_mfc71_rtl_x86_---.msm` (has mfc71.dll)
- `vc_user_stl71_rtl_x86_---.msm` (has msvcp71.dll)
- `vc_user_mfc71_loc_rtl_x86_---.msm` (has mfc71*.dll localized versions)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the merge modules for MFC 7.1 to be in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\redist`, assuming that you have Visual Studio 2003 installed. (However, I can't verify that because I don't have Visual Studio on this PC.)